# How to parse content of external webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to know a way to create a curl script which can do the following things:

- Login to a specific webpage which uses a POST formular
- after the login I need to open and parse a specific url
- on this page I just need the value from a div with a specific known ID.

Is something like this possible with a PHP curl Script? Could someone give me a starting point to get this problem solved?

Comment: All of this is possible with a PHP script. You need to look into PHP's  CURL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started. I have added some comments to let you see what its doing each step of the way:

```
<?php

// Define the URL and the data you want to send
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$myvars = 'myvar1=sometestdata';

// Now try and download the webpage
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

// Create a DOMDocument for parsing the HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($response);

// Find the element with an ID of 'nav-questions'
$data = $dom->getElementById("nav-questions");
echo $data->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for this starting Point. I've one additional question. The page where I have to send the login data to is another than the page I want to download. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's what I've to do: 1. login at www.domain.tld/login.php, 2. after that just get the content of www.domain.tld/stats.html?q=name. Without logging in, I can't open the url from 2. Or am I misunderstanding your code?